# Paginação - ícone da pagina selecionada sempre no meio ou visível

Tags: javascript, css, paginação

Na minha estrutura, eu quero que seja responsiva a página selecionada sempre fique visível, se possível no meio a classe dela e a "ativa", e as demais opções fiquem ocultas, podendo aparecer se a largura da página for aumentada

```css
.paginacao {
  max-width: 870px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 52px;
}

.paginacao * {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.paginacao ul {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 118px);
}

.inicio,
.fim {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: #fff;
}

.inicio a,
.fim a {
  color: #fff;
}

.paginacao li {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 20px;
  margin: 2.5px;
  padding: 12.5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.paginacao ul li a {
  color: #222;
}

.paginacao ul li.ativo a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<center class="paginacao">
  <li class="inicio">
    <a href="#">
      <<</a>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li class="ativo"><a href="#">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li class="fim"><a href="#">>></a></li>
</center>
```

Comment: Cara não entendi direito o que vc quer... Se a tela for muito estreita vc quer mostrar por exemplo só as setas e os números <<  6  **7**  8  >>, e se a tela for alargando vc vai mostrando mais tipo <<  4 5 6  **7**  8 9 10  >>?

Comment: Exatamente isso!

Answer (score 0):

Cara eu fiz esse modelo, mas não gostei muito dele não rss... Digo isso pq ele não é dinâmico o suficiente para o meu gosto, mas não encontrei outra forma... O macete aqui é ir "apagando" os `nth-child` conforme a tela vai diminuindo usando `@media`. Dessa forma eu consegui esse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O código da imagem acima é esse!**

```css
nav {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.btns {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.ativo a {
    color: dodgerblue;
}

a {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2.5px;
  padding: 12.5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #222;
}

nav .esq a,
nav .dir a {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}
nav .esq,
nav .dir {
    z-index: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    .btn:nth-child(1),
    .btn:nth-child(10) {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:420px) {
    .btn:nth-child(2),
    .btn:nth-child(9) {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    .btn:nth-child(3),
    .btn:nth-child(8) {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:300px) {
    .btn:nth-child(4),
    .btn:nth-child(7) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="esq">
        <a href="#"> << </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="#">1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="#">2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="#">3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="#">4</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="#">5</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn ativo">
            <a href="#">6</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="#">7</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="#">8</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="#">9</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="#">10</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dir">
        <a href="#"> >> </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Só tem um problema, e se o ativo passar para outra casa? Ele vai acabar sendo oculto, mas se bem que você me deu uma base de ideia pra usar com a contagem no nth-child.

Comment: @JoãoVictor na verdade o que vc tem que se perguntar é se vcs tiver 10 página e o cara estive na tela do celular? Vc tem que fazer essa paginação "rodar" deixando o item do meio sempre ativo. Pra isso vc vai precisar de JS, eu fiz a parte do layout, agora vc tem que ver a dinâmica para ir ajustando as coisas... é um componente mais complexo do que parece... eu mesmo nunca fiz, nem sei se essa é a melhor forma. O que eu fiz foi dar un jeito de ir eliminando os elementos das pontas, mas a contagem das páginas ai é com vc